# Find repeated battles

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have one table with the following fields:

```
battle_id, winner, looser  
 1  200    44  
 2   55   366  
 3   44   200  
 4  123   200  
 5  200    44  
 6   55   366  
 7  177   205  
 8  188   211  
 9  366    55  
10   55   366
```

right now it has about 1300 records (its small), and there are about 400 players, in each battle there can only be a winner and a looser (there are no draws)

how can i find all the repeated battles? i do not want to find all the repeated battles of one player, i do want to know all the repeated battles of all the players...i know that i cam make a recursive function in php that iterates over all the battles and assign them to a matrix, but just for fun...is there a way to do it only on mysql?

And how can i optimize the table to find the repeated battles more quickly?

regards

EDIT:

For example i want the query to show:

```
battle_id, winner, looser  
 1  200    44  
 2   55   366  
 3   44   200  
 5  200    44  
 6   55   366  
 9  366    55  
10   55   366
```

Comment: How do you define "repeated battle"?  All participants are the same? And what is your table layout in SQL (what fields exist and what datatypes are used for them, and so on)?

Comment: sorry.. i just updated the question to try to make it more clearly, as you can see i want the query to find all the players that have had the same battles against other players, not importing if they won or loose

Comment: yes... it doesnt matther if the players trade spots too.. i also want to see them as well

Comment: I'm just hoping for an answer that correctly spells "loser" so I can upvote it.

Comment: @GregCase: i just copied and pasted... i thought maybe OP is from germany or something and they spell it different lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, using a self-join could result in many duplicated entries

**[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a378)**

```
SELECT
    t1.battle_id,
    t1.winner,
    t1.loser
FROM
    your_table t1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
             SELECT
                 1
             FROM
                 your_table t2
             WHERE
                 ( ( t1.winner = t2.winner
                 AND t1.loser = t2.loser )
                 OR ( t1.loser = t2.winner
                 AND t1.winner = t2.loser ) )
                 AND t1.battle_id <> t2.battle_id
    )
```

Comment: Added DISTINCT to my answer, it should not show duplicates anymore now ;) But of course your answer should work, too - I just came to hate sub-queries. As for performance, your answer might be more efficient, as you're not building up the entire Cartesian Product.

Comment: Also, see gloomy.penguin's answer as to why your query does NOT work. ;) As it's still a self-reference, every entry matches itself.

Comment: OP I guess requires the duplicates, adding the distinct clause while in `JOIN` would hide all of those, while not adding it would result in   a Cartesian product of all the matching rows. Hence I decided to use the `EXITS` clause

Comment: Nope... it doesnt work either, it only shows the same table but not only the repeated battles

Comment: Yep, same mistake as my answer had ;)

Comment: This won't work, there is no guarantee that adding the winner + the user id will result in a unique sum.

Comment: @GregCase yes, the join should be on the 2 columns
@JohannesH. it also seems I missed adding the `<>` condition, which fetch all the rows

Comment: Yup... this one worked perfectly (except for the typos lol) now i need to understand it... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT b1.battle_id,
       b1.winner,
       b1.looser 
FROM   battles as b1
group  by b1.battle_id, b1.winner,  b1.looser 
having count(*)>=2
```

Comment: You're right, now as I see your query, I got the error in mine. Deleted my answer.

You still might want to add a DISTINCT keyword to eliminate duplicates in the result.

Comment: @JohannesH. you don't have to delete yours... I don't need distinct because I am using group by and having.  I came late to the party... my answer might be wrong, lol... dunno!  I didn't test.

Comment: Sure I didn't have to. But as it's almost identical to your suggestion, just with an additional mistake built in - for what reason should it be listed here?